# Strict inequalities in real-valued continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ be a real-valued continuous random variable, such as the exponential random variable. Is the equation
$$
\mathbb{P}(X\le a) = \mathbb{P}(X < a)
$$
true? In other words, can we replace an "inequality" with its "strict" version? For instance, in the case of exponential random variable, do we have $\mathbb{P}(X\le a) = \mathbb{P}(X < a) = 1 - e^{-\lambda a}$? Intuitively, this seems correct to me (at least for non-pathological random variables) because the probability of a single point is zero, i.e., the integral of pdf over a single point is zero.
I appreciate any comment or answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's exactly right.  The definition of "continuous" for a random variable is $\mathbb P(X=a) = 0$ for all $a$.  Thus $$\mathbb P(X \le a) = \mathbb P(X < a) + \mathbb P(X = a) = \mathbb P(X < a)$$

Answer (score 2):

You can find it, for example, on Morris H DeGroot, Mark J Schervish - Probability and statistics-Pearson Education (2012), pages 101-102 under Note: Continuous Distributions Assign Probability $0$ to Individual Values:
$$Pr(a \leqslant X \leqslant b) =\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=Pr(a \leqslant X \lt b)=Pr(a \lt X \lt b)
$$
So if $X$ have continuous distribution, then  $Pr(X = a) = 0$ for each number $a$, however it does not imply that $X = a$ is impossible.